# https response on subdomain not configured for SSL (on Chrome)

Tags: nginx, ssl

**Update:** This works on Firefox but not on Chrome. Could this be a browser caching issue?

I have a website that is configured to use SSL. Following is a portion of the Nginx configuration file I'm using for this website:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name ccrs.co.in www.ccrs.co.in;
    return 301 https://ccrs.co.in$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    include snippets/ssl-ccrs.co.in.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    server_name www.ccrs.co.in;
    return 301 https://ccrs.co.in$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    include snippets/ssl-ccrs.co.in.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    server_name ccrs.co.in;

    root /home/ankush/wp_ccrs/;
    index index.php;
```

Now, the problem is that the email service provider wants us to visit `webmail.ccrs.co.in` in order to access the email accounts from browser. When I do that, however, I get the "SSL certificate invalid" error:

[image]

This shouldn't happen, because there's no wildcard A-records: only one A-record for the main domain is there. Also, the Nginx configuration doesn't mention any subdomains or wildcards (I've marked three possible areas of interest in red):

[image]

Have I done something wrong somewhere?

Comment: I tried connecting to `https://webmail.ccrs.co.in` with Firefox, and the result is the same as with Google Chrome. The reason is, the server at `webmail.ccrs.co.in` uses a certificate for `us3.webmail.mailhostbox.com`. If you click on "advanced", Google Chrome will explain this to you.

Comment: @simlev Thanks. I just happened to solve it myself. This had to do with an HSTS header set in Nginx's SSL conf file. I removed it and changed the max-age to 0, and it worked. :-)

Comment: @dotslash by removing HSTS all you've done is allow yourself to access the webmail host over plain HTTP. This is really not sensible. The correct answer is either to get your webmail provider to allow a custom SSL certificate for your domain, or change your webmail domain to be a redirect (not a cname) to the underlying webmail.mailhostbox.com. Given mailhostbox aren't enforcing SSL, the even better answer would be to switch to a mail provider that actually cares about your data security...

Comment: @Steve365 I agree, but there's little I can do in this case. It's an existing setup and the business owner won't budge. The CNAME requirement was given by the mail provider themselves, and I don't think we can change that. Will it work if I accept the subdomain URL on my server and then redirect to the webmail subdomain? I'm sorry but I don't know how the CNAME record complicates things. :|